# How can i make transparent glass like material to put it over another object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to make a 'glass' material for a 3D Eye that i'm creating, the second one (on the image) works fine since it have the colors and everything that i want, but now i'm trying to create a transparent material like a glass to put it over the second one...i'm trying and the nearest solution for this is like the one in the image..but obviously transparent..i also tried Glass BSDF but i cannot make to get it transparent.

Please help me if you can.

[image]

Comment: Make the color have less saturation and a higher value. Answering . . .

Comment: And adding to what @NoviceInDisguise said: since the fluid around the eyeball is mostly salt water, you should try an IOR of between 1.33 and 1.35. 1.33 is pure water, and the more salt it contains, the higher the IOR.

Comment: Hmm..i think that should work..but i do not know how to do that on Blender yet..it is too difficult? :/

Comment: What about using a Glass BSFD node and a Transparent node, mixed together according to a light path node, using the **"is shadow ray"** output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to change is the *Saturation* and the *Value* of the *Glass BSDF* node. With an *RGB Input* you just do this:

[image: RGB HSV]

With an image texture, you will need to do something more like this:

[image: Nodes]

This will make the saturation less, the value less, and the contrast less, allowing the glass to be much more transparent.

Here are some examples:

**High *Saturation*, low *Value*:**

[image: High sat, low val]

**Low *Saturation*, high *Value*:**

[image: Low sat, high val]

As you can see, the cubes in the background are now visible, and the environment texture behind the sphere is now much more visible.

**Other things to check:**

- The *Roughness* value
- Any mix nodes, even unused (press <kbd>M</kbd> to mute them)
- The right material is assigned to the object

Comment: Hmm, the problem right now is that the sphere is still reflecting the HDRI, if i turn it off, the material turns it off too...the sphere that needs to have the glass material only has the Glass BSDF and Material Output nodes...is there any way to make this transparent without intefering with the other object and its lighting?

Comment: Follow the *RGB Input* diagram, decrease the *Saturation* and increase the *Value*. (click on the color on the *Glass BSDF* node to get the color chart)

Comment: @beavoru Also you may want to change the roughness

Comment: `if i turn it off, the material turns it off too...` Could you please explain @beavoru ? Come on over to chat if the problem persists.

Comment: My material depends of the Hdri i'm using, if i turn off the hdri, then the material goes totally black, even if i have a light in front of it.

Comment: Totally black? Even with a light and something behind it?

Comment: Yes, totally black :/
I uploaded a new photo:
https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10987699_337711359750810_8072476765028847908_n.jpg?oh=58c3cc24f616580b219f93d1b22ee155&oe=55575EFD&__gda__=1432870516_0636628924c4bf4f196856b67da4cb13

Comment: I don't really know how to say it, english is not my main language, but what i want from the 'exterior sphere' is something like this:
https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10947289_337711563084123_4723576344319284774_n.jpg?oh=259244efa80825b8844c8cf835dabf4d&oe=55654EC0

Comment: That is how it should render. Do you have an object around the eye? Because you will need to move it or disable *Shadows* on it if that is the case.

Comment: Hmm, i think i just found the solution! i just needed to add a transparent BSDF to the glass BSDF and it looks transparent (i didn't knew it even existed, i was searching for 'translucent' or something like that) 
But now, the last thing to do is to make the light looks like a little 'white ball', but it's still not working, i'm still trying :p

Comment: That does work, sort of. You shouldn't need it though. There must be other issues in the scene. As for the other thing, make the *Roughness* less.

Comment: The Roughness of the Glass BSDF is 0.1 and it worked! IT'S Finally working :D
The original Roughness was 0... -_- i'll have to be more cautious next time..
The 'light' still isnt a perfect 'white ball'...is that because of the samples, right?
https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10968381_337713686417244_8642711211672493251_n.jpg?oh=a704689ec285d9dee015f45816895476&oe=55964023&__gda__=1432981162_3d8297cc05cf6bf0be12b94ac304f06b
Thanks for all your patience :D

Comment: Well, it was about the samples, thank you for all! ill give you the correct answer, after all, it was a step to reach the initial goal :)

Comment: Glad it is finally working :)